# Compare date and hour together

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am using Amazon Redshift . In my tables I have two columns (Date and Hour) ,along with other columns with values like

```
requestdate  requesthour
2016-10-10     1
2016-10-10     2
 ...          ...
```

Now I want to compare two dates with hours (day between 2016-10-1005 && 2016-11-1109) . Generally comparing with qyery like

```
Where date>=xxxx && date<=yyyy && hour>=hhhh && hour<hhhh
```

will give incomplete results . Can I do something which can be useful here , I tried certain things after searching the web like concat , to_timestamp but could not come up with proper query .

Can anyone help here?

Comment: What datatype is `requestdate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one explicit way:

```
where (date > xxxx or (date = xxxx and hour >= hhhh)) and
      (date < yyyy or (date = yyyy and hour < hhhh))
```

Another method would use date arithmetic:

```
where date + hour * interval '1 hour' >= xxxx + hhhh * interval '1 hour' and
      date + hour * interval '1 hour' < yyyy + hhhh * interval '1 hour'
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon ,  great start to my day to see u answer my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your date + hour to timestamp and let database to compare them

```
select (requestdate ||' '|| requesthour ||':00:00')::timestamp  between ('2016-10-10 05:00:00')::timestamp and ('2016-08-01 04:00:00')::timestamp  from bbt
```